# Call anonymous function with 'this' from function

Tags: javascript

How can I execute this anonymous function with the context of the function that's supplied from call?

```
function test(text) {
    this.first = 'test';
    console.log(this.first);
}


(function(val){
    return function(val) {
        console.log(this.first);
    }
}()).call(test)
```

Comment: Uh - why do you want to?

Comment: Because i'm learning javascript. Can we stick to the question please and why I shouldn't seek an answer for this.

Comment: I *really* don't recommend doing anything with JavaScript's OOP facilities (such as `this`) when you're learning it.

Comment: The "why" is important to understand the question well enough to give you an informed response. There are probably better ways to accomplish whatever you're trying to achieve.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

I did not incluse var self = this; before entering the return function:

```
(function(val){
    var self = this;   //add this line
    return function(val) {
        console.log(self.first);
    }
}()).call(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get the value of what `this` would be within the context of `test` with `test.prototype`.